# Define $R$ on the set $\mathbb{Q}^+$ by $p\ R\ q$ if $\dfrac{p}{q} = 2^m$ for some integer $m$. Find 3 elements of the equivalence class $[ 7 ]$

Tags: equivalence-relations

Part (a): Find 3 elements of the equivalence class $[ 7 ]$. Justify your answer.

I have so far $[7]=\{p\in\mathbb{Q} \mid pR7\}$=$\{p\in\mathbb{Q}\mid\frac{p}{7}=2^m\}$.

Part (b): Find 3 element of the equivalence class $\left[ \dfrac{3}{7} \right]$. Justify your answer.

I'm assuming this is the same set up at part (a).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For (a), take $3$ integers $m$ and $p=7\times2^m$

Comment: The problem asks not for the general form of the elements in the class $[7]$ but for you to give three *very explicitly written* elements of your choice from the class of $[7]$ in order to verify that you understand the problem.

Comment: Some examples for (a) include $7$ itself, $\frac{7}{2}$, $\frac{7}{4}$, $\frac{7}{8}$, $14$, $28$, and $56$.